# Running bash scripts with npm

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

I want to try using npm to run my various build tasks for a web application.  I know I can do this by adding a `scripts` field to my `package.json` like so:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "some build command"
},
```

This gets unwieldy when you have more complex commands with a bunch of options.  Is it possible to move these commands to a bash script or something along those lines?  Something like:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "build.sh"
},
```

where `npm run build` would execute the commands in the `build.sh` file?

Reading through [this](http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run) post it seems like it is, but I'm not clear on exactly where I'm supposed to drop my `build.sh` file or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Don't do this. Node runs everywhere. Bash does not. Whatever you're doing in bash you can do **in node**, and even CLI invocation can be done using package dependencies. Need `rm`? install rimraf, then use that in an [npm script](http://www.slideshare.net/k88hudson/advanced-frontend-automation-with-npm-scripts). `mkdir -p`? install `mkdirp` and then use that in an npm script. You have a *platform independent universal scripting language*, right there, don't then go and pretend it 'Nix only. Does the commandline get too complicated? Use a task runner like `grunt` or `gulp`. Keep it universal.

Comment: When you say "even CLI invocation can be done using package dependencies" are you talking about something like [this](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm)?

Comment: close but no, read the slides I linked to. You can install node modules that come with CLI tools, like `grunt`, or `gulp`, or `mkdirp`, etc, without needing people to have them globally installed, and then *invoke them as if they're globally installed* in an npm script, like `"build": "mkdirp build && less style/index.less > static/css/style.css && webpack"`. As long as the commands you invoke are npm-managed (i.e. in the package.json dependency listings), this just works. For any "this only works for one OS" command, use a node module that does the same thing universally.

Comment: The comments above say no, for a good reason, portability. But it depends on your audience. If it's an internal project, if your developers are on UNIX like variants (Linux/Macs etc) it is perfectly fine. If you're creating a general purpose library it is probably not...

There is distinct benefits to using BASH/SH, you will be able to achieve some things in one line that will need pages of Grunt/Gulp, but then, you're probably excluding Windows users, which may, or may not be a problem.

Comment: Why is rimraf better than rm -rf for a web application? rimraf has to do things one file at a time, and just more packages you don't need.  If a web server doesn't have bash then you can use del, but it likely has bash if the user is developing with node anyway and not .net or something. Even if it is .net it still probably has some form of gitbash or something.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The reasoning that every Node application **must** be portable just because Node is is simply incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it is, but then I didn't say that. If your Node application can only ever work on a specific OS due to native bindings etc, then that's what it is. But there is _no reason_ to not use the universal equivalents of unix tools when your code is _not_ intrinsically linked to an OS. If your code itself is universal, then use `rimraf`, and `shx`, and `cross-env`, and etc. because they're just as easy, but don't tie your codebase to one OS for no good reason at all.

Comment: There are lots of reasons to use familiar tools rather than invest time and energy meeting a portability requirement which doesn't necessarily exist in the given project.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

Its totally possible...

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "./build.sh"
},
```

also, make sure you put a hash bang at the top of your bash file `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

also make sure you have permissions to execute the file

```
chmod +x ./build.sh
```

Finally, the command to run build in npm would be

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Where would the bash file go?  Does it need to be in the node_modules `bin` directory?

Comment: you can put it wherever you want just make sure you put the relative path in package.json  eg `"build": ". ./path/to/my/awesome/build/file/build.sh"`

Comment: what is up with the . in front? Why isn't it just  "build": "./build.sh" ?

Comment: it runs the script in the current shell http://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do

Comment: What about windows?

Comment: @LajosMeszaros: In windows, I did not get bash scripts to run, but using cmd files works for me: `"build-deploy": "build-deploy.cmd"`

Comment: On Windows gitbash: `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` See [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9420) for details explaining why. Additionally, setting sh files to be opened up with gitbash by default or any other environment that can run bash scripts will get this to work.

Comment: @LajosMeszaros If you want to use windows Power Shell, then you can set this up like this:
`"build": ".\\build.sh"`

Comment: @StevenStark doing `.\\build.sh` opens the file in my default editor using VSCode terminal (GitBash).  Is there another way to run this on Windows?

Comment: @mtpultz Yes, I am finding that this actually doesn't work in all cases. In my case, I have Git Bash installed and it opens with that. But your mileage may vary here, and I do not yet have a better solution.

Comment: I'm using cygwin terminal And using "build":"sh ../../path/to/build.sh" works

Comment: In windows bash following npm script worked for me: `"name": "bash ./name.sh"`

Comment: @LajosMészáros use msys2 like a boss, obviously

Answer (score 34):

If you don't want to bother with giving permissions and the env you execute the script has for example **sh**, you could just do

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "sh ./build.sh"
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Even Simpler:**

*I routinely do this for one-offs and PoC's not involving a VCS*

package.json

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "ship": "rsync -avz deployable/* <some-server>:/var/www/some-site/sub-dir/"
    },
}
...
```

Answer (score 5):

- Just add 'bash' keyword before the file_name.sh

  `"scripts": { "build": "bash ./file_name.sh" }`
- then run "npm run build" on terminal

Comment: What is the benefit of adding the `bash` keyword?

Comment: With that you explicitly tell it to use the bash terminal to execute the command. This way your executable doesn't need permissions to be executable, because bash already handles this.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone sees this and is using **Docker** for creating an image of this application.

Regarding:

> but I'm not clear on exactly where I'm supposed to drop my build.sh file

Wherever you do decide to drop your build.sh file, make sure it is included in the Dockerfile image output, i.e. the file's path is in one of the COPY commands in the Dockerfile.

For example, if you have something like

```
scripts {
  "build": "./scripts/build.sh"
}
```

Then your Dockerfile should have a COPY command similar to:

```
COPY scripts/build.sh scripts/
```