# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command in running script in npm

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-scripts

In package.json file:

```
"scripts": {    

   "dev": "./scripts/dev_parallel.sh",

}
```

I am trying to run a shell script by typing in:

```
npm run dev
```

But I am getting following error:-

```
$ npm run dev

 ./scripts/dev_parallel.sh

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: try "dev": "/bin/bash ./scripts/dev_parallel.sh"

Comment: @Ali Not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938559/4594225

Answer (score 8):

change '.' with '%INIT_CWD%' on windows.

Before:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/drupal-gutenberg-translations && ./node_modules/.bin/drupal-js-build --css"
},
```

After:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "%INIT_CWD%/node_modules/.bin/drupal-gutenberg-translations && %INIT_CWD%/node_modules/.bin/drupal-js-build --css"
},
```