# How can I run multiple commands in package.json scripts?

Tags: javascript, android, powershell, react-native, package.json

I'm using `detox` for end-to-end testing my react-native app. When I try to run `yarn detox build -c android.emu.release` it does not run the script well `cd android ; ./gradlew assembleRelease app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release ; cd -`. This script was generated automatically by `detox init`.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "detox": {
    /*...*/
    "android.emu.release": {
        "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
        "build": "cd android  ./gradlew assembleRelease app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release ; cd -", //<<<<<<<<<<<
        "type": "android.emulator",
        "device": {
          "avdName": "NexusOneAPI29"
        }
      }
    /*...*/
  },
  /*...*/
}
```

I am struggling to run `yarn detox build -c android.emu.release` for instance. If

#### Which symbol/char do I need to use to concat commands instead of `;` on detox?

The main error I believe is: `The system cannot find the path specified.` extracted from below.

```
$ yarn detox-build                                                  
yarn run v1.21.1
detox[7600] INFO:  [build.js] cd android ; gradlew assembleRelease app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release ; cd -
The system cannot find the path specified.
detox[7600] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: cd android ; gradlew assembleRelease app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=releas
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: are you trying to have shell script inside ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937724/running-bash-scripts-with-npm

Comment: I know you are targeting Android, but what envrioment are you running the npm scripts from? Have you tried using `&&` instead of `;`?

Comment: I did try `&&` but it does not work on Powershell on Windows :'(

Comment: @G.aziz, that's a nice point, but I'd rather find the way to write it on one line :D

Comment: When you run `npm config get script-shell` via Powershell, presumably it returns the path to `cmd.exe` (as that's the default shell that npm utilizes on Windows) - in which case the `&&` operator should work OK. However perhaps when you run `npm config get script-shell` via Powershell it returns path to `pwsh` - which may be the reason the `&&` operator doesn't work.  You can set the `script-shell` to `cmd.exe` by **1)** Running: `which cmd.exe` **2)** Running `npm config set script-shell <path_to_cmd>` - whereby the _`<path_to_cmd>`_ part should be replaced with the path returned from step 1.

Comment: Thanks RobC. Unfortunatelly `which cmd.exe` does not work. It does not recognize `which` as the name of a cmdlet. Anyways I appreciate your comment. I also updated my question as it is not a problem with `npm scripts` but with `detox scripts`

Comment: @AlexandreLage - Yes, you're right, I forgot that I [created an alias for the which command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805/equivalent-of-nix-which-command-in-powershell) in _Powershell_ some time ago. You'd need to run  `get-command cmd.exe` instead. However, it's not relevant now as your issue is very different from the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `&&` to run multiple commands on any platform and any shell from npm scripts. You would expect it does not work on powershell but it does actually.

> [npm] doesn't have the exact same semantics for && (it executes the
>   second command regardless of the success of the first), but it does
>   work to string together multiple commands on a line.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4040#issuecomment-209034612

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I updated my question as I realized the problem is not using `&&` with npm scripts but with detox script. Voted you up