# How To Create Custom Terminal Command for VS Code

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal, command

I use git (like most people) for my projects in VS Code. However, I find it a hassle to first add the files, then commit them. So what I want to do is create a terminal command (maybe like `commit "message"`). What this command should do is run the following: `git add .` then `git commit -m`  plus the message they wrote in the command. From what I've seen, this shouldn't be too much of a hassle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: write a simple shell script or batch file

Comment: Use [`git commit -am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--a). It's equivalent to [`git add -u . && git commit -m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--u).

Comment: @phd THANKS! After -am i write the commit message correct?

Comment: @JMaster100 Yep, the same way as for `git commit -m`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these commands as a `script` in your package.json. To get access to the command line if your package.json is used in a Docker container you use `-bash` in front of your script, otherwise not necessary as far as I know.

To run the script you use `npm run name-of-my-script`.

You can also collect your command line instructions in a bash file and run the file from package.json as discussed here: [Running bash scripts with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937724/running-bash-scripts-with-npm)

Comment: where can i access package.json? or is it a file that i create?

Comment: Yes, it's a file you create. Install node.js globally your local computer. It comes with node package manager (NPM). Now, from your terminal, cd into the root folder of your development project (the outer root of your folder) and execute this in your command line: `npm init`. This will create package.json for you. Under "scripts" in that file you create a new script, name it as you like and can then run `npm run scriptname` from the same terminal, which will execute your script for that whole project. More info here: https://www.sitepoint.com/npm-node-package-manager/

Comment: NPM is very useful, as it can be used to run a lot of tasks like compress/minify javascript and css, compile sass, obfuscate and mangle JS (check node-babel for that), etc. etc. All tools you can dream of will be accessible with the command npm install <name-of-package>, both dev tooling and production tools. The packages come from the npm repository (for example this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

Comment: I noticed now a weakness in my suggestion for you: I don't think you can get custom commit messages into the npm script. But you can probably manage to get that variable into a regular .js file and then run that file with node from the npm script (command: node filename.js).