# A better way to manage NodeJS configuration flags?

Tags: node.js, docker, configuration, flags

I have a NodeJS application to which I need to provide various flags to customise the environment.

I'm already handling environment files with dotenv and I'm preloading it to the app from the CLI as well:

```js
"scripts": {
  "hello": "DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=/my/path/dev.env node --max_semi_space_size 64 --inspect=0.0.0.0 dist/index.js"
}
```

My question is: I'm starting to hit a situation where I need to add more and more nodejs flags in some cases - is there a better way to do it? I can't imagine passing 20 cli args (i.e. `--max_semi_space_size ...` to node in the future.

Some options I've thought/heard of are:

- moving the script logic to external file
- aliasing the node command with node + flags
- recompiling node with my custom settings

But it feels odd - I'm sure there's a way for handling that which isn't so hacky. How would you tackle that? I'm on docker too, if that makes any difference in your suggestions.

ta!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice is to create a mechanism that is reusable and can be changed on multiple levels. Many docker containers that are aimed for wide use follow this approach.

#### Hierarchical configuration

The module needs to support `hierarchical configuration`. What this means is that there will be more than one way to set-up variable and there will be a strict hierarchy, based on priority, which value will be the final value. Best practice for the hierarchy is as follows:

1. Set the value to a default value
2. Check if there is new value in the configuration file, and if so overwrite the value
3. Check if there is new value from the environment variables, and if so overwrite the value
4. Check if there is there is new value in the startup flags, and if so overwrite the value.

This approach is applicable to the `node CLI` arguments, with the exception that the hierarchy is shallower and stops at the environment variable setup.

After this chain of checks, you will have the final value for the variable.

#### Application configuration variables

Node.js has a good library called `nconf` that you can find on [github](https://github.com/indexzero/nconf). The library is allowing you to do hierarchical configuration. Here is simple example (taken from the examples in the library, trimmed for space)

```
var nconf = require('nconf');

  // 1. any overrides
  nconf.overrides({
    'always': 'be this value'
  });

  // 2. `process.env`
  // 3. `process.argv`
  nconf.env().argv();

  // 4. Values in `config.json`
  nconf.file('/path/to/config.json');

  // 5. Any default values
  nconf.defaults({
    'if nothing else': 'use this value'
  });
```

Wrap this in your own module and add the additional logic you need for the handling of the configurations

```
var myConfig = require('nconf');
..
...
..
module.exports = myConfig;
```

then use the configuration from your code as follows

```
var config = require('./myConfig');
config.get('hello');
```

This will allow you to set the default configurations in the image and overwrite them in subsequent images. Here is an example, the first image `base` will have the `hello` flag set from the file during the build and the second image will use `ENV` to overwrite the setting:

```
FROM debian:latest as base

COPY ./hello_config.json /path/to/config.json
...
...

FROM base AS second

ENV hello="Hello world from second image!"
...
...
```

Now when you create a container, you can overwrite the changes either by passing new environment file (`--env-file`) or a singe flag (`-e` or `--env`)

```
docker run --env hello="Hi from container!" --env-file ./new_conf.list secod
```

> Note that the environment file should be in a shell format FLAG=VALUE and not in json format.

#### Node CLI Arguments

The Node CLI arguments can also be handled with this approach (the only difference is that the hierarchy is stops at the CLI). The container should define the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable with the required flags in the Dockerfile as follows:

```
...
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max_semi_space_size 64 --inspect=0.0.0.0"
...
```

This can be enhanced to accept build option as well as to build the variable gradually

```
...
ARG NODE_OPTIONS=""
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="${NODE_OPTIONS} --max_semi_space_size 64"
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="${NODE_OPTIONS} --inspect=0.0.0.0"
...
```

now, during the build we can specify additional options as follow

```
docker build --build-arg NODE_OPTIONS="--cpu-prof --heapsnapshot-near-heap-limit=3" .
```

Same as the application configuration, you can use the `-env` or `--env-file` file in order to modify it for specific container.

Comment: Thank you for a long and detailed answer. I think this is a nice approach if it's the environment variables that you want to set. However - I'm not sure if that will work for the case I liseted, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I need to set the CLI flags for node itself, and I just don't want to have one, long command with tons of flags to achieve that. I want the node binary to act differently, which is set through flags. For environment variables - in docker as well - this is good solution though.

Comment: This is a generic approach, works for the CLI as well. For the `node` CLI, the environment variable is called `NODE_OPTIONS`. I will update the answer for this special case

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try in the next couple of days

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks, I believe I'll be able make my configs flexible thanks to your answer. And basically I lacked the fact that NODE_OPTIONS variable even exists... So thank you! Have a good one

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view the package.json file should be as more clean as it possible.
Usually for such cases I create `scripts` or `shell` directory, and then put all scripts into the separate bash or shell files. And finally just invoke this files from npm commands.

Something like this: [Running bash scripts with npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937724/running-bash-scripts-with-npm)

I'm not sure that usage of `nconf` for this case is good choice..

Comment: Ok, so it's basically moving it elsewhere, under a shell script in this example. Rightfully stated in the commends of the answer you linked, it might be troublesome if someone does not have the shell you're writing your script in... I'm really surprised that there's no easy way to configure nodejs cli besides classic flags. So far, I think alias is the closest i can think of, but it's not portable really, if outside of docker.

Comment: Somewhen I saw one library, that move configuration to json, but it wan't good. Also PM2 has something like this out of box

Answer (score 1):

I think this could've meet your needs:
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options

> **NODE_OPTIONS=options...**
>
> A space-separated list of command line options.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> NODE_OPTIONS='--require "./a.js"' node --require "./b.js"
> # is equivalent to:
> node --require "./a.js" --require "./b.js"
> ```

...except that:

> Node.js will exit with an error if an option that is not allowed in the environment is used

and `--max_semi_space_size` is not listed among allowed options... but you can try.

But anyway

```
"scripts": {
  "hello": "./run_node_with_options.sh"
}
```

```sh
# run_node_with_options.sh
DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=/my/path/dev.env node --max_semi_space_size 64 --inspect=0.0.0.0 dist/index.js"
```

seems like a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you, my SO didn't refresh and I didn't see your answer. But yes, NODE_OPTIONs was one of the things I lacked in my understanding. Hope you have a good evening/day